# Carousel with Drag support

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, carousel, jquery-ui-draggable

Can i customize caroufredsel to support dragging? something like this http://jsfiddle.net/DRVpe/

The only problem with this is it doesn't loop infinitely when you start dragging it. It should join or loop seamlessly when you move it up or down.

```
$(function() {
    $('#foo0').carouFredSel({
        circular: 'true',
        infinite: 'true',
        direction: 'up',
        scroll : {
            items: 1,
            duration: 1500,
            easing: 'linear',
            pauseOnHover: 'immediate',
        },
        auto : {
            pauseDuration : 0,
        },

    });

    $( "#foo0" ).draggable({ axis: "y" }); 
});
```

If these ain't not possible are there plugins that does what i want?

Thank You!